# Animating WPF DataGrid Row Details

Tags: wpf, animation, datagrid, rowdetails

Can anyone help me animating the WPF DataGrid row details when it's opened and closed (e.g. slides open like an accordion when the row selected and slides close when the row is not selected)? I need a simple proof of concept.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: I updated my answer by the way, it now has a closing animation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Verbose but works:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="DetailsVisibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="DetailsVisibility">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="DetailsVisibility">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4"  Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0"/>
            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <Grid.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Grid">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"
                                     Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleY">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleY">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Style>
            <Grid.Children>
                <TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit"/>
            </Grid.Children>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

**Edit:** By taking care of the `DetailsVisibility` manually in the `RowStyle` the return animation now works too.

Note that the DataGrid's height does not shrink back once the details are collapsed, which might be a bit problematic. This is a known problem of the VirtualizingStackPanel, if you can afford it you could change the `DataGrid.ItemsPanel` to a normal StackPanel (If you have a lot of data this will greatly slow down the application since every row will be created right away, even if not visible).

Also: Pressing *Ctrl + A* is great fun.