# ListBox item load animation

Tags: wpf, listview, animation, listbox

I want to create user control based on ListBox (ListView) with such animation: the items in listbox do not loads all at once, they have to load step-by-step (item-by-item, first then second, then third, etc.) with some timeout between them.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 10):

You could use a Blend SDK behavior for this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, Source={StaticResource SampleData}}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:FadeAnimateItemsBehavior Tick="0:0:0.05">
            <b:FadeAnimateItemsBehavior.Animation>
                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
            </b:FadeAnimateItemsBehavior.Animation>
        </b:FadeAnimateItemsBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListBox>
```

```
class FadeAnimateItemsBehavior : Behavior<ListBox>
{
    public DoubleAnimation Animation { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Tick { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_Loaded);
    }

    void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IEnumerable<ListBoxItem> items;
        if (AssociatedObject.ItemsSource == null)
        {
            items = AssociatedObject.Items.Cast<ListBoxItem>();
        }
        else
        {
            var itemsSource = AssociatedObject.ItemsSource;
            if (itemsSource is INotifyCollectionChanged)
            {
                var collection = itemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged;
                collection.CollectionChanged += (s, cce) =>
                    {
                        if (cce.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
                        {
                            var itemContainer = AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(cce.NewItems[0]) as ListBoxItem;
                            itemContainer.BeginAnimation(ListBoxItem.OpacityProperty, Animation);
                        }
                    };

            }
            ListBoxItem[] itemsSub = new ListBoxItem[AssociatedObject.Items.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < itemsSub.Length; i++)
            {
                itemsSub[i] = AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ListBoxItem;
            }
            items = itemsSub;
        }
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            item.Opacity = 0;
        }
        var enumerator = items.GetEnumerator();
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = Tick };
            timer.Tick += (s, timerE) =>
            {
                var item = enumerator.Current;
                item.BeginAnimation(ListBoxItem.OpacityProperty, Animation);
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                }
            };
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

`Tick` specifies the time between when items are started to fade in. `Animation` is the animation applied to the Opacity for the fade in, it can be set in Xaml to be very costomizable (e.g. easing functions and fade time).

**Edit:** Added new item fade in (only works if ItemsSource is used and implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`)

(*Use code snippets like this with caution, if at all. This code is mainly for demonstration purposes and giving a general idea of how this can be approached. This could probably also be done using Blend 4's native `FluidMoveBehaviors` if availabe.*)

Comment: Thanks for such qualified answer!

At last, how could I animate items without Opacity property, but with Visibility property. I tried so much but can't do that.

Comment: You can animate Visibility using a [`ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.objectanimationusingkeyframes%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587374/animating-wpf-datagrid-row-details/5588022#5588022) you can see an example.

Comment: Thanks! It was so tried to find answer becouse such animation (or behavior) has not special name (accordion? - may be the best!).

Comment: Glad it helped. If this answers your question you could accept it by clicking the checkmark outline on the left of my answer.

Comment: How would I use this for a canvas full of shapes?

Comment: @GeorgeR: You use an `ItemsControl` and set its `ItemsPanel` to a `Canvas`, then you can bind the `ItemsSource` and apply such a behavior to it (behavior target type needs to be changed),