# ListBoxItem animation with delay

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation

I want to play an animation with delay on each of the dynamically generated listbox items for example:

- Item[0] -> animation duration from 0 to 2 seconds.
- Item[1] -> animation duration from 0.5 to 2.5 seconds.
- Item[2] -> animation duration from 1 to 3 seconds.

and so on...(Here delay is 0.5 seconds).

How can I manage to do this?? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF ListBox animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910215/wpf-listbox-animation)

Comment: I suggest adding animation from code behind on each item load..

Comment: found a simple answer here http://blog.falafel.com/blogs/josheastburn/11-01-28/Sequential_ListBoxItem_Animation_in_Silverlight.aspx